# Web.config file not updating

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, web-config

I pasted a Web.config file from another branch into my source directory, but the older version is still showing up in Visual Studio (2015).

I'm guessing this is an issue with the IDE, but, what did I do wrong, and how do I fix it so the new version of the config file shows up?

This is a web forms project, and we are using TFS for our version control.

I overwrite the old file in the directory, open the solution and open the file within visual studio to edit. There, it displays the old version of the Web.config. The project is currently offline, but this happens both offline and online.

Comment: can you give us bit more context, What type of project, Source control. Also when you can older version is showing up, Showing up where? in Source control??

Answer (score 0):

I have a couple of workarounds in case anyone else has this problem

1) Copy and paste the content from the new file into the old file.

2) Delete the old file from the solution explorer, then add in the new one through Projects -> Add Existing Item...

I'm still perturbed by the problem, but at least there are ways around it.